# Появление кнопки через n время

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку она пропадала(это я сделал) и появлялась другая, но уже через n время?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('a').onclick = function() {
  this.style.display = 'none'; // Скрыли первую
  setTimeout(function() {      // Поставили таймер на 1 секунду
    document.getElementById('b').style.display = 'inline'; // Показали вторую
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button id="a">Первая кнопка</button>
<button id="b" style="display: none">Вторая кнопка</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если подключен jQuery, то вот еще короткий вариант на нем

```js
$("#one").on('click', function(){
  $(this).hide();
  setTimeout("$('#two').show()", 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="one">Первая кнопка</button>
<button id="two" style="display:none">Вторая кнопка</button>
```

Comment: JQuery не использую, но возьму на заметочку, спасибо.